# Exact differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a function F(x,y) whose level curves are solutions to the differential equation
$$( x^2  - 4xy )dx + x dy= 0$$

I am confused on how to solve this. The idea is to the use exact form to solve it but they don't come out to be exact. I got that

$$M = x^2  - 4xy$$
$$N = x$$

Taking the partial derivative of both does not come out to be exact. What else can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply your original equation by the integrating factor $\frac{1}{x}e^{-4x}$:
\begin{equation}
(x^2-4y)e^{-4x}dx + e^{-4x}dy=0.
\end{equation}
Then $M_y=-4e^{-4x}=N_x$, so this new (and equivalent) differential equation is exact, so you can solve it.

For information on how to come up with the integrating factor, have a look at something like https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/2233-S99/2233-l12.pdf.